# Ideal VPN setup for multiplatform and geo distributed network of servers and clients

Tags: vpn, juniper, checkpoint

As per subject. To give you an idea of what type of devices and client OSes.

Servers/network devices: Windows, Linux servers; Juniper, Cisco, Checkpoint Routers/Firewalls

Clients: Windows, Linux, iOS

We currently use OpenVPN to connect geo-distributed offices and datacenters via Linux "gateway" servers. However, OpenVPN does not fit well (or at all) with Juniper, Checkpoint and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all end users have an AD account (I'm assuming you have Active Directory in your shop) then you might want to look at the native Windows VPN server.  It supports PPTP and IPSEC tunnels so you can have just about anything connect to it.

Comment: is it easy to setup?

Comment: yes. (and im a linux/openvpn person)

Comment: Yes, it's a very easy setup.